# Prove that Euclidean distance and Uniform norm generate the same topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm teaching myself topology using a book I found. I need help proving the following.

> Suppose $M$ is the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $d$ is the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) and $d'$ is the [Uniform norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm). Prove that $d$ and $d'$ generate the same topology on $M$.

I want to do this using the following definition of topology.

> is a topology on X if and only if the following are true:
>   
> (i) X and Ø are elements of .
>   
> (ii)  is closed under finite intersections.
>   
> (iii)  is closed under arbitrary unions.

and $without$ using:

> $d$ and $d'$ generate the same topology on $M$ if and only if for every $x \in M$ and every $r>0$, there exist positive numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that $B_{r_1}^{(d')}(x) \subseteq B_{r}^{(d)}(x)$ and $B_{r_2}^{(d)}(x) \subseteq B_{r}^{(d')}(x)$.

I eventually want to prove the above theorem, but I want to start with a specific example first.

In finite sets I showed that two typologies were the same by listing all the subsets, and their unions and intersections. However there is no way to list them all because $M$ is an [Uncountable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set).

I was considering an RAA proof starting with the assumption that there does exist a subset of one topology that does not exist in the other, but then I don't know where to go from there. I was also considering an algorithm that puts circles in a square lattice, and then decreases the radii of each circle while increasing the amount of circles in the square. Talking this process to infinity, the circles can fill the square.

In short, I have no idea how to even being proving this.

Comment: You want to show that any arbitrary open set in one topology will be open in the other. The usual way to check that a set $X$ is open you need to find for every point $x\in X$ a basis element $U_x$ such that $x\in U_x \subset X$.  This shows that $X$ is the union of the open sets $U_x$.  To find such an open set in the case of comparing two metric spaces is essentially the condition given in the theorem.

Comment: @Rolf Hoyer I couldn't fit my reply in a comment, so I wrote it as and "answer".  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1). The def'n of the topology $T_d$ generated by a metric $d$ on a set $S$ is the topology whose base is the set of open $d$-balls. (I dk why you don't want to use the main theorem.)

(2). Two  metrics $d,d'$ on $S$ are inequivalent (meaning that $T_d\ne T_{d'}$) iff there exists $U\subset S$ which belongs to one of $T_d,T_{d'}$ but not the other.

Without loss of generality , suppose $U\in T_d$  \  $T_{d'}. $ Then, by (1), every $p\in U$ belongs to an open $d$-ball that is a subset of $U, $ but there must exist some $p\in U$ such that  no open $d'$-ball containing $p$ is a subset of $U.$ In particular $B_d'(p,1/n) \not \subset U$ for every $n\in \mathbb Z^+.$

So choose $q_n\in B_d'(p,1/n)$ \ $U.$ Then $\lim_{n\to \infty}d'(p,q_n)=0$ and $U\cap \{q_n:n\in \mathbb Z^+\}=\phi.$

On the other hand, for some $r>0$ we have $p\in  B_d(y,r)\subset U$ for some $y\in S$ and some $r\in \mathbb R^+. $ By the triangle inequality , $B_d(p,s)\subset B_d(y,r),$ where $s=\min( r-d(y,p), d(y,p)).$ Now $s>1/n$ for some $n\in \mathbb Z^+.$  So $d(q_n,p)\geq s$ for all but finitely many $n, $ and $\neg (\lim_{n\to \infty}d(q_n,p)=0).$

(3). Therefore if $d,d'$ are inequivalent ,there exists $p\in S$ and a sequence $(q_n)_n$ converging to $p$ in one metric but not the other.So if the set of $ d$-convergent sequences co-incides with the set of $d'$-convergent sequences, then $d,d'$ are equivalent.

(4).In your Q, show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}d((x_n,y_n),(x,y))=0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}d'((x_n,y_n),(x,y))=0$ are each equivalent to $[(x_n\to x)\land (y_n\to y)$ as $n\to \infty.] $ By (3), $d$ and $d'$ are equivalent.

(5)Remark: The converse of (3) is also true.  Two metrics are equivalent iff they have the same convergent sequences.

Comment: (1) "Idk why you don't want to use the main theorem." -  I want to eventually prove the main theorem, that is why.

Comment: (thank you, I'm trying to understand this.) When you say, $U \subset S$, is U a ball, or any subset? Can U be a union of two disjoint balls?

Comment: $U\in T_d$ \ $T_{d'}$. That is, $U$ is an open set  in the topology $T_d$ generated by $d$ but Recall that a topology on $S$ is a certain kind of set of subsets  of $S$ so "$U\in T_d$" means  the same as "$U$ is open in the $T_d$-topology."  Since $U$ may or may not be an  open $d$-ball, I had to do some work with open $d$-balls that are subsets of $U$.... BTW a convenient ,equivalent, way of saying that $(q_n)_{n\in N}$ converges to $p$ in a metric space $(S,d)$ is that for every $r>0,$ the set $\{n\in N: q_n\not \in B_d(p,q_n)\}$ is finite.

Comment: OK, I understand what $U$ is. I'm slowly trying to understand everything here. I'm still at (2)..... I do understand   "$\lim_{n\to \infty}d'(p,q_n)=0$.  However I don’t understand what $u_n$ and $\phi$ are when you say  “$U\cap \{u_n:n\in \mathbb Z^+\}=\phi.$” (did you mean $\emptyset$ )??

Comment: Yes. The lower-case Greek phi is often used for the empty set.

Comment: Okay, but what is lower case $u_n$ at the end of (2)??

Comment: Typo.  $u_n$ should have been $q_n$. ... A topology  on $S$ can be defined in terms of its closed sets instead of its open sets,  or by a closure operator . In a metric space,  the closure of a subset $U$ is the set of limit points of sequences  of member(s) of $ U$. So two metrics are equivalent iff  they generate the same closed sets iff they share the same set of convergent sequences.

Answer (score 0):

In this case we have two inequalities:

$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 \le 2\max((x-a)^2, (y-b)^2) = 2(\max(|x-a|,|y-b|))^2$, and taking square roots we have $d_2((x,y),(a,b)) \le \sqrt{2}d_\infty((x,y),(a,b))$, where $d_2$ denotes the Euclidean distance and $d_\infty$ uniform norm.

$|x-a|^2 = (x-a)^2 \le (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2$, so $|x-a| \le d_2((x,y),(a,b))$, and similarly $|y-b| \le d_2((x,y),(a,b))$, so also for their maximum, and hence $d_\infty((x,y)(a,b)) \le d_2((x,y),(a,b))$.

This will allow you to define the $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Comment: doesn't defining r1 and r2 involve using the theorem that I don't want to use?

Answer (score 0):

@Rolf Hoyer

quote:

> You want to show that any arbitrary open set in one topology will be open in the other.

I don't understand how that is sufficient. For example, I know that Euclidean metric and my "Clock" metric (see below) do not generate the same topology, on the set $[1,13)$.  However the open ball $B_{2}^{clock}(1)=(11,13) \cup [1,3)$, is open under the clock metric, and $(11,13) \cup [1,3)$ is open under the Euclidean metric on the set $[1,13)$; it is the union of two balls in Euclidean, but the union of 2 open sets in still open.

.............................................................
"clock" metric, on the set [1,13) 
$$d(x,y)=6-||x-y|-6|$$
The distance between two numbers on a clock. Ex $d(2,11)=3$ (see diagram)

 [image: clock metric]

Comment: In this case the set $[1,3)$ is open in the usual topology but not open in the 'clock' topology.  A topology is determined by what sets are open, if the same sets are open in two topologies they must be the same.

Comment: @Rolf Hoyer: I understand now, thank very much. Your comments are very helpful.